# HP Procurve 2910AL allow traffic from VLAN to VLAN

Tags: hp, vlan, access-control-list, hp-procurve

We are trying to setup so that the switch handel routing and communication between a few vlans. 
And then have a link network up to the fw.

Here is the config:

Running configuration:

```
; J9145A Configuration Editor; Created on release #W.15.08.0012
; Ver #02:11.05:16
hostname "HP-E2910al-24G"
module 1 type j9145a
ip access-list extended "105"
     10 permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
     20 permit ip-in-ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
   exit
ip access-list extended "test"
     10 permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
     11 permit tcp 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
     12 permit udp 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
   exit
ip access-list standard "allow"
     10 permit 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
   exit
ip access-list standard "test2"
     10 permit 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
   exit
ip default-gateway 192.168.16.1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.16.1
ip routing
interface 1
   ip access-group "test" in
   flow-control
   exit
interface 2
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 3
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 4
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 5
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 6
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 7
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 8
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 9
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 10
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 11
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 12
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 13
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 14
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 15
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 16
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 17
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 18
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 19
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 20
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 21
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 22
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 23
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
interface 24
   ip access-group "test" in
   exit
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   no untagged 1-2,4
   untagged 3,5-24
   ip address 192.168.16.135 255.255.255.0
   exit
vlan 861
   name "ine-Back-Localexample.net"
   untagged 4
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.32.1 255.255.255.128
   ip rip 10.250.32.1
   ip rip 10.250.32.1 receive v1-only
   ip rip 10.250.32.1 send v1-only
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 862
   name "ine-Front-Inetexample.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.32.129 255.255.255.128
   ip rip 10.250.32.129
   ip rip 10.250.32.129 receive v1-only
   ip rip 10.250.32.129 send v1-only
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 863
   name "ine-Back-Inetexample.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.33.1 255.255.255.0
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 864
   name "ine-Front-s-example.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.34.1 255.255.255.128
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 865
   name "ine-Back-s.example.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.34.129 255.255.255.128
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 866
   name "ine-esx-uplink.example.net"
   untagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.37.2 255.255.255.252
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 867
   name "ine-Front-Ihostnet-example.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.35.1 255.255.255.128
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 868
   name "ine-Back-Ihostnet-example.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.35.129 255.255.255.128
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
vlan 869
   name "ine-Client-nat.example.net"
   tagged 1-2
   ip address 10.250.36.1 255.255.255.0
   protocol "IPv4,ARP"
   exit
password manager
```

Here is a pastbin on the config http://pastebin.com/tvp5dRKp

Routing works from managmet network we can access every vlan and resources on them.
But from ex Vlan 862 we can not access vlan 861. (we can sen ICMP traffic to all host on it) but bot access any server on HTTP/SSH etc.

Any advice would be greate!

Comment: What happens if you take out the "ip rip" & "protocol" commands from both vlan stanzas?

Comment: Nothing changes :/ 

We think that the VLAN config is correct but that the ESXi 5.1 hosts have some issues. We added a host in to the fw settings for ssh and it can now connect. 
But still no go to the ESXi webpage even to it say "ANY" in the ESXi  Firewall settings. (We have also stopt the esxi firewall)